# Finding the Value not the Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been messing with this for a couple days now and trying different things. What I am working with is a row in a table that has just normal cells and text box cells. These are both initially populated from a database query. then the values in the text boxes are manipulated. What I need is to be able to read them back out and reinsert them into the DB. what I am tyring to use to re-read them is not working could anyone help me out? I know my readTblValues1() Function wont do the insert and stuff, I can figure that out I just need help figuring out how to get the values from the 5 text boxes.

Thanks!

```
$rowCount = 1;
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){
    if ($rowCount%2){
echo "<tr>

        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\">".$row['Order_Number']."</td>
        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\" size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf_1']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-23bk\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf0']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf1']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf2']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf3']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-vn4c\"><span id=\"sum".$rowCount."\"><center>0</center></span></td>
        </tr>";

    }else{
        echo "<tr>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\">".$row['Order_Number']."</td>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf_1']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-xha5\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf0']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf1']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf2']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\"><input class=\"txt\" id=\"".$rowCount."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$rowCount."\"size=\"4\" value = '".$row['conf3']."'></td>
        <td class=\"tg-031e\"><span id=\"sum".$rowCount."\"><center>0</center></span></td>
        </tr>"; 
    }

    $rowCount++;

}



    function readTblValues1()
    {

        var TableData = '';

        $('#tbTableValues').val('');    // clear textbox
        $('#confTable tr').each(function(row, tr){
            TableData = TableData 
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text() + ' '  // So-Numer
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').val() + ' '  // conf_1
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').val() + ' '  // conf0
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(8)').val() + ' '  // conf1
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(9)').val() + ' '  // conf2
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(10)').val() + ' '  // conf3
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(11)').text() + ' '  // Total
                + '\n';
        });
        $('#tbTableValues').val(TableData);
    }
```

Comment: `$(tr).find('td:eq(6) input').val()`

Comment: First of all, what is the line TableData = TableData  for?

Comment: val() can not be used on cells (td's) use it on the input fields

Comment: @RononDex it is not a single line, it is TableData = TableData + $(...).

Answer (score 0):

N A N T H you are the man, I am still learning javascript and jquery and I was fighting with that and knew it had to be something so super simple

```
$(tr).find('td:eq(6) input').val()
```

Adding the input was the answer!